# How to interpolate values between points

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have this dataset show below

```
temp = [0.1, 1, 4, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]
sg =[0.999850, 0.999902, 0.999975, 0.999703, 0.999103, 0.998207, 0.997047, 0.995649, 0.99403, 0.99222]

sg_temp = pd.DataFrame({'temp' : temp,
                        'sg' : sg})
 temp        sg
0   0.1  0.999850
1   1.0  0.999902
2   4.0  0.999975
3  10.0  0.999703
4  15.0  0.999103
5  20.0  0.998207
6  25.0  0.997047
7  30.0  0.995649
8  35.0  0.994030
9  40.0  0.992220
```

I would like to interpolate all the values between 0.1 and 40 on a scale of 0.001 with a spline interpolation and have those points as in the dataframe as well. I have used resample() before but can't seem to find an equivalent for this case.

I have tried this based off of other questions but it doesn't work.

```
scale = np.linspace(0, 40, 40*1000)
interpolation_sg = interpolate.CubicSpline(list(sg_temp.temp), list(sg_temp.sg))
```

Answer (score 1):

It works very well for me. What exactly does not work for you?
Have you correctly used the returned CubicSpline to generate your interpolated values? Or is there some kind of error?

Basically you obtain your interpolated y values by plugging in the new x values (`scale`) to your returned CubicSpline function:

```
y = interpolation_sg(scale)
```

I believe this is the issue here. You probably expect that the interpolation function returns you the values, but it returns a function. And you use this function to obtain your values.

If I plot this, I obtain this graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(sg_temp['temp'], sg_temp['sg'], marker='o', ls='') # Plots the originial data
plt.plot(scale, interpolation_sg(scale)) # Plots the interpolated data
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Call `scale` with the result of the interpolation:

```
from scipy import interpolate

out  = pd.DataFrame(
 {'temp': scale,
  'sg': interpolate.CubicSpline(sg_temp['temp'],
                                sg_temp['sg'])(scale)
 })
```

Visual output:

[image]

Code for the plot

```
ax = plt.subplot()
out.plot(x='temp', y='sg', label='interpolated', ax=ax)
sg_temp.plot(x='temp', y='sg', marker='o', label='sg', ls='', ax=ax)
```